# Are ioutil.WriteFile file mode / permission constants stored anywhere?

Tags: go

I'm following [this](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) simple go web app tutorial, and came across this method:

```
func (p *Page) save() error {
    filename := p.Title + ".txt"
    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}
```

About the value `0600` it says:

> The octal integer literal 0600, passed as the third parameter to WriteFile, indicates that the file should be created with read-write permissions for the current user only. (See the Unix man page open(2) for details.)

Are these values stored anywhere, maybe in the `os` or `ioutil` packages as some sort of constant/enum type value with meaningful names? Or are we expected to remember what each value means (or implement our own named constants)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the standard values for unix filesystem permissions.

The three digits correspond to:

- owner
- group
- other (aka: everyone)

The individual values are made up of the following bit ORed together:

- 1: execute
- 2: write
- 4: read

In the `0600` example, we have:

- `0`: means octal representation
- `6`: `write | read` for user
- `0`: nothing for group
- `0`: nothing for other

More on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions)

Comment: Thanks for the info, although it doesn't really answer my question of whether or not these named values exist in go, but it seems that from the dupe question the answer is "no"

Comment: I'm not sure whether they are enumerated in the code or not, they technically don't need to be, just passed through to syscalls.

Comment: You'd need 3^7 constants = 2187 constants to describe all values (not counting special modes). I can't imagine that many constants would be easier than just using a uint32.

Comment: I don't think he was asking about all possible combinations, just the individual bits.

Comment: @Marc: So your theory is that he wants to use constants + bitwise operations? That seems even _more_ difficult.

Comment: @Flimzy I just want to be able to write something like `perms.ReadWrite` instead of `0600` as that is clearly more readable. Is that so crazy? I assume making my own constant will not be a problem!

Comment: @Bassie: `ReadWrite` is not the same as `0600`.  `0600` would be more like `UserReadWriteGroupNoneOthersNone`

Comment: @Flimzy I see - so there are too many different types of readwrite/permission types to have a reasonably sized enum containing them all ?

Comment: @Bassie: As I just explained above, there are 2187 _regular_ modes (plus some special ones). So yes, there are far too many to have a reasonably sized enum.

Comment: @Flimzy Understood, that makes sense thank you!

Comment: You could certainly write a little helper to generate a human-readable string. But the common way to do this is not `ReadWriteExecuteUser`, it's the `rwx` version of the permissions. eg: yours would be: `-rw-------`

Comment: @Flimzy you can or them... `UserReadWrite | UserExecute | GroupRead | OtherRead` for `0744` would be tolerable and would only require around a dozen constants to cover the bottom nine bits :)